# using a variable in document.queryselector

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I am trying to access all the strong tags of a certain paragraph, therefore i looped over all the paragraphs in the document and the code explains the rest

```
let paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

  for(let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
   var element = document.querySelector(`${paragraphs[i]} > strong`)
   console.log(element)
      if( element == null) {
        continue;
      }
      else{
        var element = document.querySelector('p > strong')
        element.style = "";
        break;
      }
  }
```

when i try to do this i get an error because of this line of code

```
   var element = document.querySelector(`${paragraphs[i]} > strong`)
```

this is the error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLParagraphElement] > strong' is not a valid selector.

any help is much appreciated, thank you..

Comment: `paragraphs` items are objects. Consider changing it instead? `paragraphs[0].querySelector('strong')` this might work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a selector string such a `p`, `.class` or `#id` in the place of that variable, not an HTML element.

I suppose you're actually looking to execute the [`querySelector` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) on the paragraph element instead of the `document` object:

```
var element = paragraphs[i].querySelector(':scope > strong')
```

<sup>(See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) for what `:scope` does.)</sup>

Comment: i changed my line to yours but it still doesn't work... thanks for answering..

Comment: @AliReda-M What exactly does not work? You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) explaining what problem you are trying to solve, what example html document you run this code in, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @AliReda-M Notice that `querySelector` returns only a single element. To get all `<strong>` children of a certain paragraph, you'd need to use `querySelectorAll` and iterate the resulting collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with to solve your problem:
Grab all the `strong` elements inside the `p` tags present on the page
and now you can use `.forEach()` method on the node list to manipulate elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>select strong</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><strong>strong 0</strong>something <strong>strong1</strong></p>
    <p>something <strong>strong2</strong></p>
    <p>something <strong>strong3</strong></p>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>strong inside <strong>div</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // this is a node list with all `strong` tags inside `p`
      const strongStuff = document.querySelectorAll("p > strong");

      // you can use .forEach() method on a node list
      strongStuff.forEach((strongEl) => console.log(strongEl.innerText));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or, as an executable snippet:

```js
// this is a node list with all `strong` tags inside `p`
const strongStuff = document.querySelectorAll("p > strong");

// you can use .forEach() method on a node list
strongStuff.forEach((strongEl) => console.log(strongEl.innerText));
```

```html
<p><strong>strong 0</strong>something <strong>strong1</strong></p>
<p>something <strong>strong2</strong></p>
<p>something <strong>strong3</strong></p>
<div>
  <div>
    <p>strong inside <strong>div</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need more clarification let me know.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.